# svn: '.' is not a working copy

Tags: svn

Iam getting the below error when iam trying to execute a batch file

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\test" "C:\test\Source" "*" /E  /NP /V /R:3 /XD "bin" "obj" /XF "*.pj" > %log%
svn add * --force %SVNOPTIONS% >>%log%
svn commit -m "Checking in Files" %SVNOPTIONS% >>%log%
svn info -r head >%REVISION_COMMIT%
```

Please let me know how to resolve this

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file '.svn\entries': The system cannot find the path specified.
svn: 'C:\test' is not a working copy
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

Comment: I suggest you try to focus the problem: run a command at a time, see what fails, and edit your question to reflect that. This way, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Missing things: what is your current directory? Content of %SVNOPTIONS%?

Comment: iam giving the credentials in %SVNOPTIONS%

Comment: I executed one command at a time. Robocopy is working fine.Iam getting that error while adding a files to svn repo

Comment: Can you indicate if c:\Test and c:\Test\Source are working copies?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `"*"` doesn't evaluate to hidden files and folders. That means your `.svn` directories containing the administrative area of the working copy aren't copied.

Skipping the `"*"` alltogether should work:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\test" "C:\test\Source" /E  /NP /V /R:3 /XD "bin" "obj" /XF "*.pj" > %log%
```

**Edit:** This assumes test is a working copy, and test\Source isn't. I'm not sure what your current situation is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checkout the files from SVN into your TEST folder?

Comment: Again i wanted copy the contents of source to svn working path and if any new files and changed files should be added to svn repo. But Robocopy is working fine, but iam getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: Your current path is not C:\test\Source but c:\test,
(svn: 'C:\test' is not a working copy)
Thus, you either add pushd C:\temp\Source to your script
or you change it to 
svn add C:\temp\Source* --force %SVNOPTIONS% >>%log%
svn commit C:\temp\Source -m "Checking in Files" %SVNOPTIONS% >>%log%

Note, if C:\temp\Source is not a working copy, 
i.e it does not refer to any location at svn repository, then you have to prepare it first:
Given you would like to add your files to svn://svnserver/trunk/Source folder,
you have to run missing following command:
svn checkout svn://svnserver/trunk/Source C:\temp\Source